# Refine Mesh Surface adding points on faces. CGAL

Tags: cgal

I want to add some new vertex on my Surface_mesh using a texture to define where the points must be added. ( remeshing by texture design).

Using uv data I have generated a list of 3D points that must be added.This part is ok.

But I don't have any idea how to add one by one all theses points and get a correct triangle list.

Which system will be the best ?

Convert my 3D Mesh to Polyhedron and then use create_center_vertex for each new point ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know which triangles contains the new points, then you can use the `Delaunay_triangulation_2` class from the [Triangulation_2](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/) package with the traits class [`Projection_traits_3`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Projection__traits__3.html) to get the new triangles. I'd say there is no need to convert your mesh if you only want to get a list of triangles. If you want to build a mesh from a triangle soup, you can use the function [`polygon_soup_to_polygon_mesh()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__combinatorial__repair__grp.html#ga2ba9722ec8472a1455107ffce7145e46).

Comment: Thanks, using Delaunay_triangulation_2 is ok to generate new faces inside original face. It works fine, thanks.